# Trying to understand Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a CDH3 psuedo-distributed cluster on my Ubuntu Server vm. It seems to be working fine as far as I can tell. So far, I have tried to run some example MR programs and they have worked as expected.

I was messing around with one example, which summed all numbers in a csv, comma delimited file. Instead of outputting just the sum, I added another line that output the total number of KV pairs that it added together. I have two lines of output.collect :

```
output.collect(new DoubleWritable(0), new DoubleWritable(count));
output.collect(new DoubleWritable(1), new DoubleWritable(sum));
```

What I expect is

```
0.0     273        // correct number of KV pairs

1.0     14803.957104520006          // correct sum of all values
```

instead, i am getting

```
0.0     2.0

1.0     273.0

0.0     2.0

1.0     14803.957104520006
```

I only have 2 output.collect statements, can someone please explain why I have 4 output lines? I know for sure that the program is counting and adding correctly, but I am having trouble understanding what it is doing behind the scenes and why it is behaving like this?

Can it potentially be doing a distributed add without me asking it to?

My code: http://pastebin.com/KX3uVN27

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay someone in my office explained to me what is happening. The example code that I had, which was a word count program, used the "reducer" as a "combiner", which in effect simulated a distributed associative add.

Comment: Here is the code, fixed!
http://pastebin.com/LEzcWds6